# Request Lose Cookies

Tags: php, symfony, angular, cookies

When I make a request through the angle to symfony in the request header I send 2 cookies phpsessid and auth, but sometimes symfony receives the modified auth cookie or with missing characters this problem only happens in the mobile phone as the "cut" Of the cookie does not have any standard and is not regular I do not know what could be causing this modification. (In the image below I show an example of how I make the request for symfony through the angular).

[image]

I already looked on the net if the problem was the size of the cookies but what I found is that the maximum size is 4 kbytes and my cookies have the total size of 865 bytes.

[image]

Below are two examples with the same request in which symfony in one of them receives the auth correctly and in another one already receives the auth with enough missing characters.

Correct: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4B7qL7YgkN3RmxUaTZDa1hxckk

Invalid: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4B7qL7YgkN3bTdTdG01U0JMc3M

**Some Information That May Be Useful**

Symfony bundles used

- FOSRestBundle
- JMSSerializerBundle
- NelmioApiDocBundle
- NelmioCorsBundle
- LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Packages on Angular

- none

Comment: Might be a problem of missing URL encoding on the cookie value - is Header supposed to take care of that already? If not, try applying it to the value before you pass it to Header.

Comment: I've tried this but it still does not give